# Sticky Footer isn't sticking

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

**Question background:**

**I have edited this question to show the changes I have made**.

I am using a sticky footer (as used here:http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) on my website

**The Issue:**

Previously, this question was asked on how I could get the footer to stick. I now have it sticking to the bottom of my page ***but*** a new issue has reaered in that the footer is 'splitting', as shown:

[image]

**Code:**

This is my Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Images/FMFCFavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Images/FMFCFavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>FMFC</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo">FM<b>FC</b></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href='@Url.Action("Home", "Home", null)'>Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="eventPadding">
                    <div class="row" id="features">
                        @foreach (var eventDetail in @Model)
                        {
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3>@(eventDetail.Name)</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <p>
                                            <img src="@(eventDetail.Image)" class="img-circle" id="eventImages" alt="Work">
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <h5><b>Date: @(eventDetail.Date)</b></h5>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <h5><b>Time: @(eventDetail.Time)</b></h5>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <h5><b>Location: @(eventDetail.Location)</b></h5>
                                        </p>
                                        <p class="text-center"><h5>@(eventDetail.Description)</h5></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts.js"></script>
</body>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

</html>
```

Styles:

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -4em;
    }

    .footer, .push {
        height: 4em;
        background-color: #a9a9a9;
    }
</style>
```

If I increase both the `.wrapper margin -4em` property to a larger value along with the `.footer -4em height` property then this increases the wrapper and footer em properties to a value such as `7` the split does not occur (or they merge) obviously I do not want this, as shown:

[image]

I want the height to be kept at `4em` and `-4em` respectively.

If I have more than one `Panel` on the page then this issue does not appear:

[image]

Any help in sorting this issue out will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post a demo with generated *static* HTML and CSS.

Comment: How about use an inspector in your browser to see what causes that?

Comment: @ManojKumar I've added a JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because, you have given same CSS styling for both `.footer` & `.push` whereas the element `.push` is present in other container. Hence it is splitting when content is less.

To remove the splitting:

Either you should remove `.push` element or remove `push` class from that element.

```
 <div class="push"></div>
```

Or you can remove CSS styling for `.push` element and give only for `.footer` element.

```
.footer{
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

By this you splitting issue will be resolved. And to make it fixed to the bottom of the window, add the below CSS styling to `.footer` and also add `padding-bottom: 4em;` for `<body>`. Here `4em` is because is given as the height of the `.footer` is also `4em`. It will prevent the content to get hidden behind `.footer`.

```
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
```

And you can give some `padding-top` for look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the example from the Bootstrap page.

[Sticky footer with fixed navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/)

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 126px 0;
}

.rowPush{
  padding-bottom:50px;
}


.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}


.footerStyle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 126px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.footerStyle h5 {
  line-height: 126px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="eventPadding">
      <div class="row rowPush" id="features">
        Details
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        1 2 3 4 5
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footerStyle text footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h5>Copyright &copy; 2015</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

```
html, body{
     height: 100%; 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xwfvwxa/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace .footer, .push with this. That should do the trick:

```
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xwfvwxa/4/

Answer (score 0):

You've given a background color to `.footer` and `.push`.  So when there's no content on the page, you're seeing the `.push` div (looks like it's doubled).  When there IS content on the page, the `.push` div is technically behind the footer because of the negative margin on the body.

Remove the background color from your `.push` div:

```
.footer, .push {
    height:4em;
}
.footer {
    background-color:#a9a9a9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [working example](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/JYPjVN)

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html,body{
  height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto -150px; /* minus the height og the footer */
}

#push, footer{
  height:150px; /* push needs same height as footer */
  clear:both;
}

footer{
  background:red;
}
```